Flutter Localization - Can buttons be equal dimensions based on localized text?
I'm building my first production Flutter app that needs to support localization.  I have everything setup and working when it comes to text replacement.  I have a widget that shows a series of steps and each step having their own properties associated with them.  At the bottom of this list of steps are 3 buttons that a user can click to add a step.

These button dimensions are manually defined based on what would fit the widest text.  When I switch to Spanish (based on Google Translate for now) it cuts off one of the buttons.

Is there a way to define the dimensions, based on localization, in such a way where whatever ends up being the widest button is what all three buttons are set to?

Don't use the fixed width.

Take a look at Boxy.  It lets you do almost any layout computation you want.

Try to find the string with the maximum length from the list, measure its width using TextPainter, and apply that width to all text containers.

@DroidFlutter I like this idea!  I should have some time today to give it a try and see how it goes.  I was trying to get the Auto Size Text package to work but because of my layout it wasn't working without hacking at it so this sounds promising.

Glad you like the idea! Hope it works out smoothly for you. Let me know if you run into any issues or need any help as you give it a try!

@DroidFlutter - Your suggestion worked like I hoped it would.  If you could write up an answer for it I'll make sure to mark it as the answer for you.

Sure, I have added code for it.

Try below code...
List<String> stringList = ["Lasers", "Even End", "Board Stop"];
List<String> stringListLanguage = ["Laseres", "Final Parejo", "Parada Del T"];

  double getTextWidth(String text, BuildContext context) {
    final textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 16); // Define the text style
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: text, style: textStyle),
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    )..layout();

    return textPainter.size.width; // Return the width of the text
  }

Get max length text from list
    String maxLengthText = stringList.reduce(
        (current, next) => current.length >= next.length ? current : next);

    String maxLengthTextLanguage = stringListLanguage.reduce(
        (current, next) => current.length >= next.length ? current : next);

    double maxWidth = getTextWidth(maxLengthText, context) + 10;
    double maxWidthLanguage = getTextWidth(maxLengthTextLanguage, context) + 10;

After getting max length, use it as width for Container
   Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            Container(
              decoration:BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),color: Colors.blue[100],) ,
              width: maxWidth,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Lasers',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              width: maxWidth,
              decoration:BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),color: Colors.blue[100],) ,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Even End',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              width: maxWidth,
              decoration:BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),color: Colors.blue[100],) ,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Board Stop',
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            Container(
              width: maxWidthLanguage,
             decoration:BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),color: Colors.blue[100],) ,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Laseres',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              width: maxWidthLanguage,
              decoration:BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),color: Colors.blue[100],) ,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Final Parejo',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              width: maxWidthLanguage,
              decoration:BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),color: Colors.blue[100],) ,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Parada Del T',
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ],
      )),


If you want to use fixed-width and equally sized boxes and ensure that the text inside fits within these boxes, you can use the auto size text package. This package adjusts the fontSize of the text to fit within the container.

I do worry a little bit about the text being smaller for Spanish users BUT I do like the feature of grouping those widgets so the font size is the same across all of them in the group.  I'll give this a go when I can and give this question a bit more time to see if there are additional answers.  Thank you!
